# Xamarin Forms Reverse PushModalAsync

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

So in Xamarin, one of the navigational methods of pulling up a new page is the PushModalAsync call, which brings a new page without any *normal* navigational pieces. But not having pieces like a back button also removes the ability to navigate backwards... So is there a way to UN-pushmodalasync per se? Call up a page and then put it back down, like with a button or something along those line? I know Push Async does that, but I'd like the full page without the navigation bar at the top. A page separate from everything else that can be pulled up and pushed back down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to dismiss a Forms modal, use `PopModalAsync()`.  You will have to add a button or some other control on your page that triggers this.

Comment: Thank you much! You're a lifesaver! Can't believe I didn't find that earlier! :p