# Back button is not showing on Navigationbar . Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

When show screen, navigation is showing at the Top.But Back button is not showing.
When i use Navigation.PushAsync method then back button is showing.

I am using below code.

```
 Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginSelection());
```

how can i show backbutton at left side of Modal screen.

Comment: As Modal page is like a Modal popup it will be on top of the other pages, that's why you don't see a back button. You can just add a "X" on right or left top portion and call `Navigation.PopModalAsync` in the click event

Answer (score 2):

When you call `PushModalAsync()`, you are creating an another Navigation Stack of Modals.Thus, your `LoginSelection()` page is not added to the Page Navigation Stack,but it is added on Modal Navigation Stack.
Thus,there are no pages in your modal stack and that's why back button is not appearing

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link:-

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69952/navigationpage-pushmodalasync-and-back-button`

[Xamarin Forms Reverse PushModalAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160286/xamarin-forms-reverse-pushmodalasync)

Comment: He asked for Xamarin.iOS (native) as per the tags, your answer though being relevant is not he asked.